# How to get the arraylist out android studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am unable to get my `ArrayList` out when it's on a different page. I would like to get the `ArrayList` out Android Studio.

This is `CartActivity` class:

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<CartItem> cartList;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CartAdapter adapter = null;
        cartList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CartAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_cart_item, cartList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is `ProductActivity` class. It's where the data is being stored into the `ArrayList`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(ProductActivity.this);
    textViewPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    textViewInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewInfo);
    textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    ivProduct = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProduct);
    btnAddToCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
    spinnerQuantity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuantity);


    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();
    userID = b.getString("userID");
    productID = b.getInt("productID");
    Cursor results = myDB.checkProduct();
    if (results.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: no data found!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (results.moveToNext()) {
            id = results.getInt(0);
            name = results.getString(1);
            price = results.getString(2);
            info = results.getString(4);
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(results.getString(5));
            image = results.getBlob(6);
            if (id == productID) {
                textViewName.setText(name);
                textViewInfo.setText(info);
                textViewPrice.setText("S$" + price);

                int[] quantityValues = new int[quantity + 1];
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < quantityValues.length; i++) {
                    quantityValues[i] = counter;
                    counter++;
                    quantityList.add(Integer.toString(quantityValues[i]));

                }
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                ivProduct.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quantityList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinnerQuantity.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addCart(View v) {
    cartList.add(new CartItem(name, price,spinnerQuantity.getSelectedItem().toString(), image, id));

    Intent productListIntent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
    startActivity(productListIntent);

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect, in general, that variables in one activity would be accessible from another activity?

Comment: you should pass array list from Activity A to B, after that you able to add new item to that, see this ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250407/4146722

Comment: isn't variables in one activity be accessible from another activity?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best practice, but you can make your arrayList

```
public static ArrayList list;
```

Then you can access it from ather activity using {class_name}.list

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should impliment **Serializable** in CartItem class and then pass from ProductActivity to CartActivity . Like this :

**ProductActivity** class.

```
Intent productListIntent= new Intent(this, CartActivity .class);
  productListIntent.putExtra("cartlist", ArrayList<CartItem>mcartItem);
startActivity(productListIntent);
```

and in  **CartActivity** class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
      ArrayList<CartItem> mycart= new ArrayList<CartItem>();
          mycart= (ArrayList<CartItem>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cartlist");
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CartAdapter adapter = null;
        adapter = new CartAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_cart_item, mycart);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: have you implement Serializable in CartItem class?

Comment: I have just tried but there is systex error productListIntent.putExtra("cartlist", ArrayList<CartItem>mcartItem);

Comment: I have just implemented Serializable in CartItem class.

Comment: you may try  "productListIntent.putExtra("cartlist", cartList);" this.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help after I tried productListIntent.putExtra("cartlist", cartList); it didnt have any systex error anymore but it still didn't work. but after I run an update it just suddenly work.

Comment: If the above code is helpful for your problem then please accept this answer because other person also have to face the same problem soo this solution may be helpful for them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your list of your data via intent(as Intent is a message passing Object) From ! activity to another activity. For that you have to make that class Parcable or Serializable . How to make a class Parcable in andriod studio read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32177307/7134908). Then put thah class into the intent that you are passing to startActivity() method like

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key",your_list);
```

or

```
 intent.putExtra("key",your_class)// incase of single object
```

then get it to the onCreate() method of second activity like

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("your_key")
```

or

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra()//  incase of single object
```

Hope it will help your

Comment: Thanks for your help