# How to pass an Arraylist of Events through an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a list of events from one Activity to another one using intent, this is how I tried to do it:

**on Activity 1:**

```
ArrayList<Event>  eventsSelected= new ArrayList();
eventsSelected.add(new Event(Color.RED, dateClicked.getTime(), "event1"));
eventsSelected.add(new Event(Color.RED, dateClicked.getTime(), "event2"));
eventsSelected.add(new Event(Color.RED, dateClicked.getTime(), "event3"));
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("eventsSelected", eventsSelected);
startActivity(i);
```

but I didn't find how to get it on the second activity, I tried it this way but it didn't work :

**on Activity 2:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<Event> selectedDates = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("eventsSelected");
```

Comment: implements Serializable to your object class

Comment: I didn't clearly understand how to do that! see i'm new on android, may you please explain more @JohnJoe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: try    `Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras() ;  ArrayList<Event>  aaa= (ArrayList<Event>) data.get("eventsSelected");`

Comment: You should put that on the answers section not comments. @jigarsavaliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to clarify it works this way

```
ArrayList<Event> eventsSelected = new ArrayList<Event>();
intent.putExtra("eventsSelected", eventsSelected);
```

and in the second class

```
ArrayList<Event> eventsSelected = (ArrayList<Event>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("eventsSelected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implements Serializable to your object class

```
public class Event implements  Serializable {
}
```

Also

```
i.putExtra("eventsSelected",eventsSelected);
```

Comment: where should I place that?

Comment: In your Event class

Comment: I don't have an Event class

Comment: just to be clear, I'm using a Calendar over there and that's what I'm using the Events for

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras() ;  
ArrayList<Event> aaa= (ArrayList<Event>) data.get("eventsSelected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have to must have to  implements class Parcelable or Serializable while you are passing it through an `Intent`.
 look at my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992819/7134908) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44629789/7134908) answers.
Hope it will help you!!